# C++ - Error 'undefined reference' while using templates with function

Tags: c++, function, templates, global

I have a function `transpose` declared in a header file `global.h` as shown below:

```
template <size_t M, size_t N>
extern void transpose(array <array <float, N>, M>&, array <array <float, M>, N>&);
```

The function is defined in another file `global.cpp` as shown below:

```
template <size_t M, size_t N>
void transpose(array <array <float, N>, M>& a, array <array <float, M>, N>& b)
{
    // This can be made faster
    for (size_t i = 0; i < M; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            b[j][i] = a[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

However, the following function call:

```
transpose<dim, dim>(jacobian, jacobian_transposed);
```

throws the error:

```
undefined reference to `void transpose<23u, 23u>(std::array<std::array<float, 23u>, 23u>&, std::array<std::array<float, 23u>, 23u>&)'
```

The variable `dim` is defined in the `global.h` as shown below:

```
static constexpr const int marker_num = 10;
static constexpr const int dim = (2 * marker_num) + 3;
```

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14400157/template-error-undefined-reference). Are there any ways to keep the function definition in the `global.cpp`?

**Edit:** I read the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file) of which this question was marked as duplicate. That along with the answer from @Xirema helped me realize that I have three options:
1) Implement function in the header.

2) Implement function in a file with '.ipp' extension and include it inside the header.

3) Third option is explicit instantiations like:

```
template <size_t M, size_t N>
void transpose(array <array <float, N>, M>& a, array <array <float, M>, N>& b)
{
    // This can be made faster
    for (size_t i = 0; i < M; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            b[j][i] = a[i][j];
        }
    }
}
template void transpose(array <array <float, dim>, dim>& a, array <array <float, dim>, dim>& b);
template void transpose(array <array <float, dim>, 2>& a, array <array <float, 2>, dim>& b);
```

Which of the above is the best method (I am trying to follow the best coding practice)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Template definitions cannot have their implementation in a .cpp file: it *needs* to be in the header.

But, if you're a reasonable, logical person who wants to separate the declaration and definition of a function into two different files, there is a work-around you can use.

Put the implementation in a file with a file extension the compiler won't recognize (a common idiom is to use .ipp), and then at the end of the header file, add the line `#include "impl.ipp"` (or whatever filename you go with). This will enable correct use of the template.

Comment: Is it considered a bad practice to move the implementation to header? Also, if I have a file with `.ipp` extension will it work with all compilers? Is this better than the header file method?

Comment: @skr_robo They do not *need* to be in a header, but if you are going to share the implementation across multiple files, the implementation must be visible to all users. A C++ compiler does not care what you name the implementation file. When it spots a `#include` statement, it looks for the file and effectively pastes it into the file being compiled. You can `#include` any syntactically correct file, including some abusive tricks that load a csv file from Excel or Matlab into an array. You can `#include` syntactically incorrect files if you want to, but the compiler will choke over it later.

Comment: Okay. I am trying to see which one is more professional approach. Please see the edit.